# iPhone:How to make an integer array and store values in Obj-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know a simple thing, which i couldn't get it is that i want to store 10 values in an integer array dynamically and then i have to check that stored values and compared with the current values whether it is same or not in some other condition. Initially i tried same like C array, int temp[10], but seems to be that is not possible to set and get method, then i tried NSNumber like below,

In AppDelagate file,

```
    NSMutableArray *reqID;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) 
NSMutableArray * reqID;

@synthesize reqID;

........................

........................

........................
```

In Some other file,

```
int rd = (1+arc4random() % [arr count]);

[myDelegate.reqID addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:rd]];
```

then i need to check,

```
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        NSUInteger anInt = [[myDelegate.reqID objectAtIndex:i] unsignedIntegerValue];

        if ( anInt==rd )
        {
            rd = (1+arc4random() % [arr count]);
            break;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn' work as expected, i.e array value doesn't give proper value. i don't know how to use integer array in Obj-C and handle it to access later etc.

Could someone please explian me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the stuff Emil has pointed out,

```
myDelegate.reqID = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

doesn't give you an array with 10 slots in it, it gives you an empty array with a hint to the runtime that you are eventually going to put 10 things in it.  So, if you run youre loop from 0 to 9 before you have added 10 objects, you'll get an NSRangeException because you'll run off the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should declare the property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * reqID;
```

Second, you will need to actually create an NSMutableArray somewhere. For example:

```
myDelegate.reqID = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

Note that you must use `myDelegate.reqID` rather than `reqID` so that the object is retained.

(Personally I would use ordinary C arrays here... )

**Edit:** remember to do `[reqID release]` when you've finished with it.

**Edit 2:** Here's how to do this with C arrays:

In your class, add an instance variable `int *reqID`. Then declare a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int *reqID;
```

Then to allocate space for your array, do:

```
myDelegate.reqID = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

Then to access your array you can use [] syntax:

```
int a = myDelegate.reqID[i];
```

Then when you have finished, do:

```
free(myDelegate.reqID);
```

Comment: I modified everything as you have suggested. But i am getting crash when reading that mutablearray variable like below.
I added, myDelegate.reqID = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; in AppDelegate file DidFinishLaunching.
In another file, i am trying to access it like below:
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
 {
   // GOT CRASH IN THIS LINE.. 

         
NSUInteger anInt = [[myDelegate.prevquesid objectAtIndex:i] unsignedIntegerValue];
            .....................................  
 }

I have also tried to do as C arrays, but i don't know how would you add "property" when using C arrays.

Comment: Small correction in my previous comment. I added "prevquesid = = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];" in AppDelegate file DidFinishLaunching, not the one as in my earlier comment.

Comment: what is the message you get when you crash?  is it EXC_BAD_ACCESS by any chance?

Comment: [myDelegate.prevquesid objectAtIndex:i] will crash because the array's empty and doesn't have anything at i=0 (the value of i as it enters your for loop)

Comment: Hi, I have resolved it by using NSNumber to fill the array values. For ex initialize with 0's: 
prevquesid = [ [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10]; 
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
  NSNumber *myInt = [ [NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:0 ];
  [prevquesid insertObject:myInt atIndex:i];
 }
And accessing the same in later files, is able to work properly without any crashes. Thank you.